# ecmascript 6 syntax for declaring prototype default values using Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, es6-class

When creating classes in javascript, you can set a default value by accessing the function's `prototype`.

```
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype.get = function() {
        return this._value;
    }
    Foo.prototype._value = 'foo value';
    var foo = new Foo();
    console.log(foo.get()); // logs "foo value"
```

How can I achieve a similar effect using ecmascript 6 `class`?

```
    // this doesn't work
    class Bar {
        get() {
            return this._value;
        }
        // how to declare following default value properly?
        _value: "bar value"
    }
    var bar = new Bar();
    console.log(bar.get()); // logs undefined
```

Comment: ES6 does not have property declarations on classes, only methods.  It is a suggestion for ES7 though: https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties

Comment: @TbWill4321: Those don't create prototype properties though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class` syntax does only allow you to define methods, but it still just creates a constructor function with a `.prototype` object. You can set the default value exactly as in ES5:

```
// this does work
class Bar {
    get() {
        return this._value;
    }
}
Bar.prototype._value = 'foo value';
var bar = new Bar();
console.log(bar.get()); // logs 'foo value'
```

Of course you might just want to create and initialise an instance property instead:

```
// this does work
class Bar {
    constructor() {
        this._value = 'foo value';
    }
    get() {
        return this._value;
    }
}
var bar = new Bar();
console.log(bar.get()); // logs 'foo value'
```

---

Another solution that has become rather common is to use a getter, which will be defined on the prototype, which of course has the downside that the value is created on every access of the property:

```
class Bar {
    get() {
        return this._value;
    }
    get _value() {
        return 'foo value';
    }
}
```

If you insist on using only `class` syntax, [ES2022 will have static blocks](https://2ality.com/2021/09/class-static-block.html) which could also be abused to create a prototype property:

```
class Bar {
    get() {
        return this._value;
    }
    static {
        this.prototype._value = 'foo value';
    }
}
```