# Is there a syntax in JavaScript class definitions to declare a property on the prototype?

Tags: javascript, class, properties, prototype

I know that data properties on prototype objects are considered an anti-pattern, but there are some use cases. One is the @@toStringTag property, which is used by `Object.prototype.toString()` to return "[object Foo]" instead of "[object Object]". Placing that property on `Foo.prototype` seems the right thing to do.

But - how to do it the right way? I could

- create a static initializer that calls Object.defineProperty on the prototype (or just assigns it)
- call defineProperty on the prototype just after the class declaration
- define a getter like this: `get[Symbol.toStringTag]() { return "Foo"; }` (used on MDN)

I dislike all three options, because the `class` Syntax tries very hard to hide the prototype-object. The first two variants undo that. The third doesn't, but it creates an unnecessary function.

Declaring a property `[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Foo";` is what I want to avoid, because it creates that property on every instance of `Foo`, not on the prototype.

Maybe I am too obsessive about writing code the right way. But before I send a request to TC39 - is there something that I missed? Has `class` a syntax to declare a prototype property?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34185731/5089567

Comment: As it should be non-enumerable, you can't `[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Foo"` or `prototype.[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Foo"`. Use getter, as MDN recommends. If you want it to not appear in the type, use `defineProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, `class` syntax tries hard to hide the prototype object, and it has achieved just that, to the point where it is not possible to place data properties on the prototype object without explicitly mentioning it. You are not missing anything.
As you mention, this is generally an antipattern, so the syntax discourages it, and I doubt a proposal to add it would be received well by TC39.